# Regarding good coding practices, what is meant by "Useless return at end of function and method"?

Tags: python, function, spyder, conventions

I'm using Spyder to create a web scraper, and things are moving smoothly so far. As a rookie, Spyder's Code Analysis function is something I find useful for improving the standard of my code. However, while I usually understand its instructions/recommendations, I've recently run into a bit of a blip. I'll post some sample code first:

```
def payments(): #### This is line 59 on the editor. Preceding it is another function with a a format similar to this one.
    """Obtains data on the weekly payments in the country"""
    html = get(source["Payments"]).text
    html = bs(html,"lxml")
    location = "/home/oduduwa/Desktop/Python Projects/Financial Analyser/CBN Data/Payments.csv"
    def file_check():
        headings = [i.text for i in html.find_all(width="284")][:10]
        headings.insert(0, "Date")
        if isfile(location) is False:
            with open(location,"w") as file_obj:
                writer(file_obj).writerow(headings)
                return
    file_check()
    file = open(location,"r").read()
    dates = [i.text.strip()[8:] for i in html.find_all("th",colspan="2")]
    values = [i.text.strip()[4:] for i in html.find_all(width="149") if i.text.strip()[4:]!=""]
    values = array(values).reshape(int(len(values)/10),10)
    values = insert(values,0,array(dates).transpose(),axis=1)[::-1]
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if values[i][0] not in file:
            with open(location,"a+",newline=("\n")) as file_obj:
                writer(file_obj).writerow(values[i])
    return
```

The code runs fin and does everything it should. What I don't really understand, however, is Spyder's statement that there's a useless return call in the code block. Here's what it says specifically:
[image]

But from what I gather, every function call is necessary in this coding block. What could I have missed? Thanks for your time!

Comment: in python, a function that ends returns `None`, if you add an empty return you also return `None` so its useless to add an empty return because it returns that anyway

Comment: In addition to the comment above, there are times when it does make sense to include just `return` or `return None` inside a function, EG some statements of the form `if len(list_of_useful_things) == 0: return None; else: do_something_useful()`, where `return` is used in an `if` condition to make sure the function doesn't do anything else if that condition is true. But if it's the final statement in a function, there is no point in including `return` or `return None`, because it is equivalent to the default behaviour if the `return` statement is not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python functions implicitly return `None` by default. The following function definitions are equivalent.

```
def foo():
    pass

def foo():
    return

def foo():
    return None
```

In my opinion, it is good practice to either

1. have no `return` statement at all - this indicates that you are not supposed to assign a name to the return value when calling the function, or
2. explicitly `return None`, to indicate "no result" for a function that could return a meaningful value, or
3. use just `return` to make a function that returns no meaningful value stop execution.

Example for situation 1:

```
def switch_first_last_in_place(lst):
    'switch the first and last elements of a list in-place'
    lst[0], lst[-1] = lst[-1], lst[0]
```

This function implicitly returns `None` and you are *not* supposed to issue

```
result = switch_first_last_in_place([1, 2, 3])
```

Example for situation 2:

```
def get_user_info_from_database(username):
    'fetches user info, returns None if user does not exist'
    if user_exist(username):
        return query_db(username)
    else:
        return None
```

This function explicitly returns `None` to indicate a user was not found. Assignments like

```
result = get_user_info_from_database('Bob')
```

are expected. The part

```
else:
    return None
```

is *unnecessary* but I like being explicit in cases where `None` is a meaningful return value.

Example for situation 3:

```
def assert_exists(thing, *containers):
    'raise AssertionError if thing cannot be found in any container'
     for container in containers:
         if thing in container:
             return
     raise AssertionError
```

Here, `return` is merely used to break out of the function.

---

I don't like the bare `return` at the end of the functions in your example. It is not used to end execution and those functions cannot return other values. I would remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I guess I misunderstood the syntax

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood. The warning isn't talking about any of the functions you are calling. It's referring to your use of the `return` keyword.

This function:

```
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    return
```

Is equivalent to this function:

```
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
    return None
```

Which is equivalent to this function:

```
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
```

The warning is saying, that your `return` statements are useless, and are not required.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain